# How to show only month year in form.io Date / Time Component

Tags: reactjs, date, datetimepicker, formio

Currently in [form.io Date / Time Component](https://docs.form.io/userguide/form-building/advanced-components#date-and-time) show like below image(day, month and year)
[image]

But i need to show only month and year like below image
[image]

I am set minMode = "month" or "year" but not working

How can i show this type of picker?